# Prove that Cauchy$(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is not an exponential family

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Cauchy$(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is defined as $\frac1\sigma \frac1 {\pi(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2})}$

I need to prove that this is not an exponential family. Here's what I've attempted.

I rearranged it to become

$\frac1 {\sigma\pi} e^{\ln\biggm(\frac1 {1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}\bigg)} = \frac1 {\sigma\pi} \big({e^{-\ln(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2})}}\big)$

Not sure where to go from here. It seems intuitive that I won't be able to separate the exponent into a function just involving $x$ and a function just involving $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. I'm not sure how to state it, or if I've taken it far enough though.

Comment: Your last identity is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, I think I fixed it!